# Is there anyway I can use Mac OS 9 on Ubuntu?

Tags: mac

Is there something in virtual box i can use or a different virtual system altogether, or even a dual-boot with Ubuntu 12.04 and Mac OS 9. I have thousands of dollars worth of software that can only be used in Mac OS 9. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you using a PC with Ubuntu in it? or are you using a Mac with Ubuntu in it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will be helpful: http://www.osnews.com/story/23321/Howto_MacOS_9_on_Ubuntu_Using_SheepShaver/

Comment: Please include details from the link. If the  linked site were to go down, this answer would be of little value to future users.